# How to iterate over a linked list of values input by a user?

Tags: python-2.7, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list to store integers input by users, then iterate over them and print it out, how can get this working?

```
class linkedlist:
    def __init__(self,a,x):
        x= int(raw_input("Enter Number: "))
        self.a=[]

    def addusersinput():
        a.append(x)
        print a


    def removeitem():
        i=int(raw_input("Select number position: "))
        print "You can remove a number from this list by selecting it's poistion,/n the first number has a position of 0, 2nd number has a position of 1 and so on"
        a.pop(i)


class node:
    def __init__(self,c,value):
        self.c=i+1 #next node
        self.value=a[i+1]

    def show():
        print self.c
        print self.value
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any classes for this. If this is a homework assignment, ask your professor or  a TA if you need help.

```
linked_list = []
inputs_to_record = 10
for input_number in range(inputs_to_record):
    user_input = raw_input("Enter a number:\n>")
    while not user_input.isdigit(): user_input = raw_input("Try again - must enter a number:\n>")
    linked_list.append(int(user_input))

for number in linked_list: print number
```

> it's poistion

You've spelled position wrong, and incorrectly used an apostrophe. It's is a contraction for "it is." You wanted "Its," meaning "belonging to it."